# Object.setProtoTypeOf() isn't setting the __proto__ property, instead it's setting the object directly

Tags: javascript, prototype

So, I'm new to `setProtoTypeOf()`, and from what I know of it, it adds the 2nd parameter of that function as the `__proto__` property of the object specified in the 1st parameter. But with function objects, this doesn't set the `__proto__` property, but the object itself. For example:

```
function function1() {

}
 Object.setPrototypeOf(function1.prototype, HTMLElement.prototype);
console.dir(function1.prototype)
//Output: accessKey: (...)
ariaAtomic: (...)
ariaAutoComplete: (...)
ariaBusy: (...)
ariaChecked: (...)
ariaColCount: (...)
ariaColIndex: (...)
ariaColSpan: (...)
ariaCurrent: (...)
ariaDescription: (...)
ariaDisabled: (...)
ariaExpanded: (...)
ariaHasPopup: (...)
ariaHidden: (...)
ariaKeyShortcuts: (...)
ariaLabel: (...)
ariaLevel: (...)
ariaLive: (...)
ariaModal: (...)
ariaMultiLine: (...)
ariaMultiSelectable: (...)
etc.
//(These are all the properties of the HTMLElement's prototype object)
```

I would have expected it to just log out this though:

```
constructor: ƒ function1()
__proto__: Object
```

And then, if you were to expand that `__proto__` property, THEN it would log out the "ariaAtomic: (...)
ariaAutoComplete: (...)
ariaBusy: (...)
etc." Because `Object.setProtoTypeOf()` sets the `__proto__` property of the specified object, not the object itself, right? I've tested this with traditional objects, and it works how I would expect it to.

Comment: I think the way it looks is going to depend on the way a particular browser `console.dir()` implementation works. With your code, the Firefox console makes it clear that all those properties are in fact on the `HTMLElement.prototype` object.

Comment: It's best to ignore the existence of `__proto__`. Just assume it's not there and stick to `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf`. There is no reason not to.

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(function1.prototype) === HTMLElement.prototype` returns true. So, works as intended

Comment: *"The use of \__proto__ is controversial and discouraged. It was never originally included in the ECMAScript language spec, but modern browsers implemented it anyway. Only recently was the \__proto__ property standardized by the ECMAScript 2015 specification for compatibility with web browsers, so it will be supported into the future. It is deprecated in favor of Object.getPrototypeOf/Reflect.getPrototypeOf and Object.setPrototypeOf/Reflect.setPrototypeOf*" [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Comment: This is really just confusing console output for objects that have enumerable getters on their prototype. Notice that you get the exact same output if you had used the deprecated `__proto__` setter instead of `Object.setPrototypeOf`. And it's not related to the fact that your target was a function either, it's the same on normal objects.